# How to know whether this page has malware or not?

Tags: linux, webserver, malware

Google adwords is reporting that the following page has malware on it. Can anyone help me how to scan/track it properly? and what to do to remove this malware?

http://www.goodtherapy.org/blog/distress-tolerance-dialectical-behavior-therapy-0117134

I have tried with **"maldet" scan** already and nothing found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not be hosting malware now but you have relatively recently:

http://safebrowsing.clients.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=goodtherapy.org

The script could be randomly injected or perhaps your ISP is cleaning things for you in the background.  In any event, your site has been and probably still is compromised and you should be doing a security audit and looking for altered files.